# search with grep for words beginning and ending with

Tags: regex, grep

How to grep something which begins and end with a character

```
ABC-0
ABC-1
ABC-10
ABC-20
```

I wanto to grep -v for ABC-0 and ABC-1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not clear what you mean. If you want a character at the start and double digits at the end, you could use

```
^[A-Za-z].*\d\d$
```

If you only want a hyphen and then a *single* digit, use:

```
^[A-Za-z].*-\d$
```

If you don't care how many digits there are (one or more), but there has to be a hyphen, use:

```
^[A-Za-z].*-\d+$
```

If none of those are what you want, please give more information... the first sentence of your question doesn't really tally with the rest.

Comment: You forgot the quantifier for `[A-Za-z]`.

Comment: Or rather, I forgot other things after it - we don't know whether A00-10 would be acceptable. Fixed though, thanks.

Answer (score 11):

If you are trying to match words use `\b` as the word delimiter, like this:

> \b[A-Za-z]-\d+\b

from [this reference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html):

> **`\b`** - Matches at the position between a word character (anything matched by
>   `\w`) and a non-word character (anything matched by `[^\w]` or `\W`) as well
>   as at the start and/or end of the string if the first and/or last
>   characters in the string are word characters.

Comment: While you can get the PCRE behaviour in some versions of grep with "grep -P", \b is buggy and doesn't behave reliably; in particular, it doesn't detect tab as a word boundary character ('\b/www\n' broken in GNU grep 2.6.3).  Had this worked, it would be the neatest answer (and I wish it did work!)!

Comment: Using `\b` is useful when you want to recognize words separated by spaces or other punctuation characters, to split things like "word1,word2". Other times you will prefer `^` and `$` to only split on spaces and match things like "file.ext" as a single word.

Answer (score 5):

For your example

```
egrep -v "^(ABC)-(0|1)$"
```

is the answer. For the common case, please look at Jon's answer

`^` marks the start of the pattern, `$` the end. `|` means `or`